# No route matches with member in resources Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following routes:

```
resources :sources do
    member do
      get 'parse'
    end
  end
```

And the following controller:

```
class SourcesController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_admin!

 def index
   @sources = Source.all
 end

 def parse
 end
end
```

I have a form that I would like to trigger the parse action in the controller. I do it like this:

```
<% @sources.each do |source| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= source.name %></td>
    <td><%= source.url %></td>
    <td>
      <%= form_for source, url: {action: 'parse'} do |f| %>
        <%= f.submit "Parse this source" %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>


<% end %>
```

And I keep getting:

```
 Failure/Error: visit "/sources"
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"parse", :controller=>"sources"}
```

Also, in my rake routes, I can see this:

parse_source GET   /sources/:id/parse(.:format)   sources#parse

Why is that? Isn't my action defined?

Answer (score 1):

Use `form_for [:parse, source]`.

The problem is you're not adding the `source` itself to the URL, so there is no `id` as required by the route. You'd need to use `url: { action: 'parse', id: source.id }`, but the `[:parse, source]` form is clearer and shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I get this if doing so:  ``undefined method `model_name' for Symbol:Class``

Comment: Interesting. Why would I not be able to do form_for [source, :parse] - Doing ``url: { action: 'parse', id: source.id }, method: :get`` works...

Comment: Sorry, I had that backwards. It's `[:parse, source]`.

Comment: meagar, Where is the documentation for this? I am looking at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for and it doesn't explain so.

Answer (score 0):

> form_for source, url: parse_source_url(source.id) do |f|

You can also use the above to resolve this